# How to keep all words on the same line in the tabular environment?

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


 \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Prisoner 1} \\ 
    & &  C & D \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{4em}{Prisoner 2} & C & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1, 1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 2} \\ \cline{3-4}
    & D &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 2}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 0}\\ \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

, which produces the following table:

[image]

My question is: how to keep the text "Prisoner 2" on the same line? Because now "2" is pushed to the line below "Prisoner".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you enclose within an `\mbox` will not break.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Prisoner 1} \\ 
        & &  C & D \\ \cline{3-4}
        \multirow{2}{4em}{\mbox{Prisoner 2}} & C & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1, 1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 2} \\ \cline{3-4}
        & D &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 2}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 0}\\ \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

Please note that constricting line breaks will put the text at risk of overflowing:
[image]

Comment: Much cleaner and simpler would be to replace `\multirow{2}{4em}{Prisoner 2}` with `\multirow{2}{*}{Prisoner 2}`.